# Is energy lost on a powered, long, but unused DC power line? And how?

Tags: low-power, bus, energy-transmission, wakeup

I am designing a super low power sensor system with a master and multiple, simple clients connected with a 4 wire bus (differential signals, GND, DC low voltage VCC on shielded twisted pairs).
The length of the bus would be up to 30 m / 100 ft, with 4-16 clients.

The master collects nodes' data and regularly send them via GSM.
Batteries are present only in the master (3.7 V lithium).

Here is how I would do it

- 99% of the time, nodes are just unpowered
- master is also in very low power deep sleep (<50 µA)
- it wakes the sensors up every hour for readings by simply powering the VCC line via a mosfet, long enough to collect all readings. If needed, the nodes charge a cap before they boot up (they can run on 1.8 V and a few mW, so parasitic-like power is easy).

But **I would like the sensors to be able to wake the sleeping master** as well, in case an alert occurs on their side.

Any deep-sleeping sensor would wake up due to an interrupt, read its value, then wake the power-hungry master up to have its data sent as soon as possible.

**How naive is it to leave the VCC bus line powered, without losing significant energy**?

Sure,

- loss on a long wire is expected when power is drawn
- there are also probably electromagnetic losses due to voltage variation

However,

- nodes use only ~10 µA of current in deep sleep, so power loss due to ohm's law shall be mostly insignificant, isn't it?
- 99% of the time, no AC signal will even be on the bus lines except during very short transmission time. Only DC.
- baud rate and data volume is extremely low (~4 byte/sensor every hours, to help with reliability of course)
- I plan on using LTC1481 (RS85 with 1 µA sleep mode)

Note that the way nodes are able to wake the master up is probably another question (e.g. by checking activity on the differential pairs with a standalone opamp before the master).

Comment: A block diagram would be nice

Comment: If you have enough power/energy budget to leave it energized and some scheme to wake when needed and deep sleep otherwise, do that.

Comment: Still I would love to know if, where and why I would lose energy on a wire just because it is energized - even with almost no load nor variation on it. I can have 30+m of wire and soething tells me it seems be too easy. I plan on 6+ month minimum battery time on a single 18650, if not years

Comment: Unless there is a fault, the loss from the wire itself (and leakage through its insulation) is probably negligible compared to those 10 uA sleep currents in the nodes.

Comment: You say the Vcc line is DC, but how *clean* that DC is will determine extra losses.  If there is an AC ripple on the line, then that can capacitively couple to the other wires and consume current from the supply.

Comment: Perhaps old waxed-cotton/natural rubber insulation had measurable leakage, but modern insulation would have less than nanoamp leakage at IC supply voltage over 30 m. A bigger factor would be keeping the individual nodes dry.

Comment: @Aaron there would only be the battery voltage on the line, but I might indeed try to ground the differential lines, because *they* might catch AC/radio signals if left floating. Now all pairs are shielded.